# How to import require module in browser javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to make a jupyter notebook extension and I am following [this repo](https://github.com/jfbercher/jupyter_varInspector) . I needed to run python code using javascript for which I am trying to use the [npm python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

To import the package, I tried using `require` module but its not working because it is not supposed to be run on browser and requires `nodejs`. I tried searching for other ways to run nodejs on browser and found stuff like browserify etc. However , the file `main.js` in the repo linked above is using the `require` module comfortably. How is it doing so? What am I missing? Below is the code and the error I get in the browser. I have installed `require` and `python-shell` module using npm already.

Code:

```
define(['require','PythonShell','base/js/namespace', 'base/js/events'], function (require,Jupyter, events) {
  

  var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
  PythonShell.runString('x=1;print(x)',null,function(err,results) {
    console.log(results);
  });

  function load_ipython_extension() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
  return {
    load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension,
  };
});
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Well, even browserify didn't work, still getting the same error . I don't want to build a python backend or something for such small issue :(

Comment: I know what I am referencing says it is for JupyterLab, but it could be worth trying as a test workaround, see the last section [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/what-is-the-2022-way-to-display-javascript-in-a-python-notebook-in-jupyter-lab/12318?u=fomightez). I'd also suggest that you find a more recent model to use a resource. Things have advanced in the classic Jupyter notebook even since 2017 and it may be this is better sorted following a more recent model. No guarantee. And maybe you are just referencing that one by using the more recent source stuff that is linked form there?

Comment: Ok , thanks . I had already tried the pyodide thing mentioned in the answer below but it probably doesn't support import of all modules like pytorch or tensorflow.

Comment: Also, there seems to be shortage of resources on jupyter notebook extensions. One of the reasons, why I am trying to build one. The one I linked above is the only relevant one I could find.

Comment: @nmsharma. One reason you may be finding there is a shortage is because the classic notebook interface was/is limiting. That is why the current modern generation of Jupyter is JupyterLab. JupyterLab opens up a lot of options. In fact, the next version of the classic notebook, version 7.0, will have very different underlying machinery. Version 3 of JupyterLab already has a very different way extensions are built & deployed than the original JupyterLab. I suspect the new Jupyter notebook versions 7 & beyond will have extension development and deployment more in line with JupyterLab v.3.

Comment: Oh , thanks for the insight, didn't know about that. Should've tried to stay updated lol

Comment: If you are interested in that see the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) and the [Jupyter Blog](https://blog.jupyter.org/). There's a lot of up-to-date extension-related content on the Discourse Forum.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the library you are trying to use, [python shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) was designed for node.js, as stated in their package description:

> A simple way to run Python scripts from Node.js with basic but efficient inter-process communication and better error handling.

Because of that, you cannot use this package in the browser. There are probably lots of alternatives, and I found this package through some quick googling: [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/index.html) (note, I have never used this myself, I just found it).

Comment: But then how did that repo end up using it , that too in like 2017?

Comment: I tried pyodide, it seems to work but didn't support import for deep learning modules like pytorch. It was still a useful answer, thanks !